# How to deep link to Notes app?

Tags: ios

With other apps, like twitter, for example, you could simply use twitter://xxxxx to link to it, but how do you do the same with the Notes app?

Thanks

Comment: This may not be possible—the Notes app isn't a web service. And what would happen if someone else tried the link? (: Then again, maybe the iCloud web interface has something.

Comment: @seaturtle thanks. But if you share the icloud link and open it on an ios device, it does open up the Notes app

Comment: What are you trying to do, share with someone else who doesn't have a Mac or iOS?

Answer (score 5):

The URL scheme for the Notes app is `mobilenotes://`

Source:

https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/

Comment: Great! Now, how do you deep link to individual notes?

Comment: Also, that URL seems to be defunct.

Comment: on deep-linking to individual notes: if you share a notes and copy it's link, you can retrieve it's direct link.

Comment: The URL scheme `mobilenotes://` still works for me on iOS 14.7

Comment: but how do you use that to link to a specific Note?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is different on macOS and iOS.

On macOS, the URL scheme is `notes://showNote?identifier=???`; on iOS, it is similar, but uses a different scheme: `mobilenotes://showNote?identifier=???`.

The `???` here is annoying and subtle to get out.  It is *not* accessible via AppleScript on the mac, even though AppleScript *can* see an "id", that is an unrelated value.  You need to use the Shortcuts app and the "view content graph" action on the note that you want to extract the URL from, double click the "note" in the graph, then the "INNote" (on iOS<15/macOS<ventura) or "LNNote" (on iOS>=16/macOS>=Ventura), then fish a UUID out of the gibberish you see in the text field there.

On iOS 16 / macOS Ventura, the format changed subtly, and it is now case sensitive, as well as *opposite from the case shown in the content graph*.   Federico Viticci discovered this change [and documented it in a blog post late last year](https://www.macstories.net/ios/creating-lock-screen-widgets-for-specific-notes-via-the-apple-notes-url-scheme/).

Answer (score 0):

I just got this to work.

I opened iCloud Notes in a browser on my Mac.
I navigated to the specific note that I wanted.
I copied the URL.

I have clipboard sharing enabled between my Mac and my iPhone. (Explaining that setup is off topic for this question.)

I opened Chrome on my iPhone, iOS 15.1.
I pasted in the copied http:// URL into the Chrome address bar.
I changed the http:// to mobilenotes:// and clicked Go.
Chrome attempted to search for the entire URL string.

I copied the changed URL string.
I opened Safari on my iPhone.
I pasted in the copied mobilenotes:// URL into the Safari address bar and clicked Go.
Safari asked me if I wanted to open the note in the Notes app.
I said Yes.

Notes opened, on that specific note, a couple of layers deep in my Notes hierarchy.